# Eliminating parameter to get Cartesian equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$x = \sin(t/2)$
$y = \cos(t/2)$

$-\pi \le t \le \pi$

How would I go about getting the Cartesian equation of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square both equations ans use the Pythagorean identity to eliminate the trig terms. You will get the Cartesian equation of (part of) the unit circle

Comment: That gives me:

$sin^2(t/2) + cos^2(t/2) = 1$

But how do I simplify that further?

Comment: $x^2=sin^2$ and $y^2 = cos^2$ etc.